# How to parse a data from JSON that inside of a {}?

Tags: ios, json, swift, string

Hey i am trying to parse some datas from the API down below but as you see in the link some datas are under {0},{1}... sort of formation, i assume that why i couldn't parse the data by using this line of code?

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v2/financials/income-statement/AAPL?datatype=json

```
func updateStockData(json : JSON)
{

    if let revenue = json["financials"]["5"]["Revenue"].double
    {
        print(revenue)
        stockPriceLabel.text = "$" + String(revenue)
    }
    else
    {
        print("unavaiable")
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `Codable`, which allows you to deserialize JSON data directly into a desired type.

Answer (score 0):

the value for the key "finiancials" is an array, so you have to index it using an integer. Also, revenue in the JSON is a String, so you have to read it as such and manually convert it to a double value:

```
if let revenueString = json["financials"][5]["Revenue"].string, let revenue = Double(revenueString) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work even if i change the .double with .int

Comment: The type of "Revenue" is string. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with [`SwiftBooster`](https://github.com/3pehrbehroozi/SwiftBooster/) library (written by myself) and it worked well. No need to create struct or class for modeling json or casting the `String` value to `Double`.

```swift
import SwiftBooster

func updateStockData(json : JSON)
{

    if let revenue: Double = getValue(input: response.responseJsonObject, subscripts: "financials", 5, "Revenue")
    {
        print(revenue)
        stockPriceLabel.text = "$" + String(revenue)
    }
    else
    {
        print("unavaiable")
    }
}
```

Note that you should use `5` for the second key, not `"5"`

Comment: For full transparency I think you should mention it’s your own library.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. Edited